# The program is getting stucked at pipe.to(device)

Tags: python, stable-diffusion

The code gets stuck at `pipe.to(device)`.

```
from auth_token import auth_token
from fastapi import FastAPI,Response
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import torch
from torch import autocast
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline
from io import BytesIO
import base64

from torch.cuda import empty_cache

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_credentials= True,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"]
)

device = "cuda"
model_id = "CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4"
pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(model_id,revision="fp16",torch_dtype=torch.float16,use_auth_token=auth_token)
print(torch.cuda.get_device_properties(0).total_memory)
pipe.to(device)


@app.get("/")
def generate(prompt : str) :
    with autocast(device):
        image = pipe(prompt,guidance_scale=8.5).images[0]

    image.save("testimage.png")
    empty_cache()
 
    return {"out":"hello World"}
```

I installed all the latest versions of `transformers`, `diffusers` and `scipy`.

I have a GPU with 4 GB vRAM.

Comment: What does your `total_memory` print statement print out? Could you print versions of mentioned libraries?

Comment: The total_memory is 4294639616 .

FastAPI version : Version: 0.101.0

Torch : Version: 2.0.1

Diffusers : Version: 0.19.3

Answer (score 0):

4 GB of vRAM is quite low. Check [this](https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/optimization/fp16) post to see improvements. To get it to work under 4 GB, I'd suggest:

```
pipe.enable_sequential_cpu_offload()
pipe.enable_attention_slicing(1)
```

Also, you should assign it to the `pipe` like this:

```
pipe = pipe.to(device)
```

Comment: Tried this but idk why it didn't worked out for me